# How to dynamically position a listbox in relation to textbox in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently programming a grid with winforms. I have multiple textboxes which are making up the cells each. When I click on the cells I want to Display a listbox (it is a single predefined listbox that I added via the designer before, thus the same listbox for each of the cells).

Now my question is how can I Position the listboxes under the textboxes?

The Events I Need to use I know already (as I'm using a Framework there I needed to use the Events there and already know the appropriate one where I can make the listbox visible and invisible).
I have handlers for the current TextBox in the Event. The Problem I have is that I'm not sure
how I can use These informations to Position the Listbox itself.

Thus which commands do I Need to use to Position the listbox?

Comment: Create a __common__ `Enter` event for __all__  your `Textboxes`. Put this code into it:  `TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender;
            listBox1.Location = new Point(tb.Left, tb.Top + tb.Height + 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the textboxes to the enter and leave event
Use the sender to make it work for all textboxes.

TextBox TextB = (TextBox)sender;"

Then use the textbox location X and Y to set the list box.
You need to add to the Y the height of the textbox and the space you want it to have under you're textbox.

"listBox1.Location = new Point(TextB.Location.X, TextB.Location.Y + TextB.Height + 5);"

Use the code below and it works

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TextB = (TextBox)sender;

        listBox1.Location = new Point(TextB.Location.X, TextB.Location.Y + TextB.Height + 5);
        listBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is there also a good way there to decide when to Display it below or above the TextBox? (and related to that: I had to Position it 8 px to the left (-8 for x) so that it was starting directly below the TextBox any clue why that could have been the case?

Comment: For the x-8 i don't know why that is. But if you need to give x-8 and you're problem is solved,its solved :). And for you're question about when to Display it below or above , what do you mean by that ? when the list box goes of the screen ?

Comment: exactly. thus if the row where the listbox is created on is so far down on the screen that the list would only be displayed partly instead of fully

Comment: Maybe better ask a new question for that with some explanation about you're form.Can it scroll and so on.i have it working for a fixed window but don't know if it will work if you can scroll.