# Windows Form scrolling simultaneously multiple ListBoxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I am working with WindowsForms and I have two ListBoxes. I can successfully scroll both ListBoxes separately but I want to "synchronize" scrolling. So when I scroll the `ListBox1` I want to also scroll `ListBox2` at the same time, select the corresponding field of `ListBox2` and align it at the same position with `ListBox1`.
I have already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626876/how-to-dynamically-position-a-listbox-in-relation-to-textbox-in-winforms), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945992/scrolling-two-listboxes-windows-form-at-same-time), and many other posts.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: current status]

And here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: target]

Comment: This is doable but why reinvent the wheel? Use a DataGridView with two columns instead.

Comment: So you checked those other posts, what is not working? Current state of your question, would be a duplicatication of the posts you are referring to.

Comment: @41686d6564 indeed DataGridView could work but that would require a lot of changes in the project. I will check and try to implement it. Could you please guide me also on my initial question on how to synchronize the two list boxes scrolling?

Comment: @nilsK many things that they are referring are missing in my project (for example syncListView1_OnVerticalScroll).

Comment: @curious I'm sorry but I don't have the time right now to write and test code for something that I believe is useless. Again, don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use a DataGridView, ListView, or any control that can have columns instead of trying to _mimic_ the behavior.

Comment: Or use ONE ListBox and combine the two things that are being displayed into that one LB...

Comment: [Renatas M's comment under this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27946346/2590375): '(...)delete your [Sync] list boxes. Build solution and try to find SyncListBox in Toolbox window. It should be displayed as a gear like this and named SyncListBox. Drop them in you form and do what I wrote in answer'. But i'm with the other commentors: use a ui control, that already suits your needs instead of fiddeling around. Less clunky, more pretty ;)

Comment: A LIstView probably doesn't need too many changes, you can easily arrange your data in Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thank you guys for helping me. I used `DataGridView` with two columns as @41686d6564 suggested and it works like a charm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a complicated task. However, with the help of [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7554/Getting-Scroll-Events-for-a-Listbox), I managed to reach this solution.

You will have to create a new control similar to `listBox` that has the event `Scrolled`, this can be done using this method.

Inside your project, right-click the project node and select **Add** > **Add User Control (Windows Forms)...**, name it **ScrollingListBox.cs**. It will appear in the **Solution Explorer** along with a file with name **ScrollingListBox.Designer.cs**, right click on the latter file and delete it, then select **ScrollingListBox.cs**, right-click on it and select **View Code**, or press F7, then replace its contents with this code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Scroll
{
    public partial class ScrollingListBox : ListBox
    {

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        [Category("Action")]
        public event ScrollEventHandler Scrolled = null;

        private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
        private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 0x8;
        private const int SIF_RANGE = 0x1;
        private const int SIF_PAGE = 0x2;
        private const int SIF_POS = 0x4;
        private const int SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10;
        private const int SIF_ALL = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS;

        private struct ScrollInfoStruct
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public int fMask;
            public int nMin;
            public int nMax;
            public int nPage;
            public int nPos;
            public int nTrackPos;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hWnd, int n, ref ScrollInfoStruct lpScrollInfo);

        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg)
        {
            if (msg.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
            {
                if (Scrolled != null)
                {
                    ScrollInfoStruct si = new ScrollInfoStruct();
                    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
                    si.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
                    GetScrollInfo(msg.HWnd, 0, ref si);

                    if (msg.WParam.ToInt32() == SB_ENDSCROLL)
                    {
                        ScrollEventArgs sargs = new ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.EndScroll, si.nPos);
                        Scrolled(this, sargs);
                    }
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref msg);
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
                components.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you will have a new item inside **Toolbox** with name **ScrollingListBox** that you can use instead of **ListBox**, and it has an event called **Scrolled** like this:

[image]

Now you can use this new listbox type for your future boxes, and for the ones that are already made, in case you don't want to delete them all and draw them again with the new type, you will need only to modify their code lines inside **Form1.Designer.cs** file as follows:

Change this line, and similar lines,

```
this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
```

to

```
this.listBox1 = new Scroll.ScrollingListBox();
```

Also this line, and similar lines,

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
```

to

```
private ScrollingListBox listBox1;
```

You can now use this event to detect a scroll that happens in one box and modify the other one accordingly, like this:

```
private void listBox1_Scrolled(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.TopIndex = listBox1.TopIndex;
}

private void listBox2_Scrolled(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.TopIndex = listBox2.TopIndex;
}
```

This will work for scrolling the scroll bar by clicking on its arrows or by grapping it with mouse, but it will not work for using the mouse wheel inside the box. I tried to use the event `MouseWheel` to solve this problem, but unfortunately, it didn't work as desired, so the only option I found is that to use both events `MouseHover` and `MouseMove` to do the trick, like this:

```
private void listBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.TopIndex = listBox1.TopIndex;
}

private void listBox2_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.TopIndex = listBox2.TopIndex;
}

private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.TopIndex = listBox1.TopIndex;
}

private void listBox2_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.TopIndex = listBox2.TopIndex;
}
```

This will work if you used the mouse wheel anywhere inside the box's white area, unfortunately, it will not work if you used it when the mouse is over the scroll bar.

Probably this will be enough to solve the problem you have, but just in case that you need a code for selecting the corresponding indices in both boxes at the same time, here it is:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Indeed that would work but I ended up using DataGridView like other commentors suggested. Thank you though.